# best way to arrange layout blocks

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I have container with 9 divs, I want to arrange the elements in the following way:

it would look something like this:

```
 _________ ____ ____
| A       | B  | C  |
|         |____|____|
|         | D  | E  |
|_________|____|____|
| F  | G  | H  | I  |
|____|____|____|____|
```

where all the elements will always be squares (width = height) and I will determine their size in percentages out of the container.
in the sample above for example A size (width and height) = 50% of width, B size = 25%. I also want to have some margin between each element about 5px.

My attempt is the following

```
    <div id="grid">
        <div class="block big">
        </div>
        <div class="block small">
        </div>
        <div class="block small">
        </div>
        <div class="block small">
        </div>
        <div class="block small">
        </div>
        <div class="block small">
        </div>
        <div class="block small">
        </div>
        <div class="block small">
        </div>
        <div class="block small">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and css:

```
#grid {width: 90%; position: relative}
.block {margin: 5px; background-size: cover; position: relative; display: inline-block}
.big {width: 50%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 50%; background-color: #eee}
.small {width: 25%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 25%; background-color: #eee}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to ingredients to the solution is a simple **`float: left`** and the use of css **`calc()`** function (which fortunately has [quite good support these days](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)) to account for mixing of those pixels with percentages:

*(I've also added `border-box` sizing so the borders, which I'm using to display the boxes wouldn't mess up/complicate the calculations)*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#grid {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 2px gray;
}
.block {
  min-width: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  border: solid 2px blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.block.big {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  height: calc(50%*4/3 - 10px);
}
.block.small {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(25%*4/3 - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="block big">
    </div>
    <div class="block small">
    </div>
    <div class="block small">
    </div>
    <div class="block small">
    </div>
    <div class="block small">
    </div>
    <div class="block small">
    </div>
    <div class="block small">
    </div>
    <div class="block small">
    </div>
    <div class="block small">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the 4/3 calculation and rounding causes this not to work correctly in Firefox.

Comment: You may be right. I'd leave it to e.g. `66.66%` and `33.33%` respectively if that's the case.